# I am trying to return a string from a boolean value in a class keeps returning true

Tags: c++, string, class, boolean

I have a constructor that prints out rows of squares. If the boolean is true it prints it filled, if its false it prints it hollow. THIS WORKS. However =*( I have another function that says wether or not its hollow or filled. It always prints filled.....

```
Box::Box(int _width, int _height, bool filled) 
{
if (filled)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
    {
        cout << "x";
        for (int j = 1; j < _width; j++)
        {
            cout << "x";
        }
        cout << std::endl;
    }
}
else if (!filled);
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0 && i != _height - 1)
        {
            cout << "x";
            for (int j = 1; j < _width-1; j++)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << "x";
        }
        else
        {
            for (int _longrow = 0; _longrow < _width; _longrow++)
            {
                cout << "x";

            }
        }
        cout << std::endl;
       }
    }
}

string Box::type() const
{
 if (filled)
 {
    return "Filled";
 }
 else if (!filled)
 {
    return "Hollow";
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you storing filled as a variable in the class itself anywhere?

Comment: its in public in my header. Should it not be there?

Comment: In the first function you pass in `filled`, in the second you don't. You appear to have 2 different variables called `filled`.

Comment: The parameter "filled" hides the member filled.For this reason it's conventional to use mFilled for the member and aFilled for the parameter.

Comment: If `Box::type()` compiles, then that suggests a member named `filled` in the class itself.   The constructor needs to set the value of that member, using the argument passed (also named `filled`).   You have confused the issue by giving the constructor parameter the same name  - in reality, they are different variables, and having an argument for the constructor named `filled` does not magically set a member named `filled` unless you write code to do that.  You haven't

Comment: oh thanks lemme see if that fixed the problem

Comment: That was it, im an idiot thanks guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Box::Box(int _width, int _height, bool afilled) 
{
mfilled = afilled;
if (mfilled)
```